# Replace prefix and suffix using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have hundreds of file with name

**MUZ-123456-KH.txt**

i want to replace this types of filename with replacing **PREFIX** and **SUFFIX**

**muz123456.txt**

MEANS:
Prefix  **MUZ-**  is replace  with  **muz**

Suffix  **-KH**   is replace  with  **none**

I have a tool which take lots of times. Can anyone help me?

Its a daily work and i get tired

Comment: Be clearer about the problem you are solving. Do you want to rename the files in the filesystem or change their name in a file of text that contains list of names. What system are you on? Are the files in one directory or many different ones. etc etc

Comment: All these .txt files are place in only one directory(Name: Muzaffar). I just want to replace the filename as i mention in above query

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace filename in same directory according to project requirement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674887/replace-filename-in-same-directory-according-to-project-requirement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of file pattern matching (with the `DIR` command) and text substitution (with the `SET` command).

I added comments to explain what each step is doing.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Process all files matching the pattern.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`DIR /B /S "C:\Path\To\Files\MUZ-*-KH.txt"`) DO (
    ECHO Processing: %%~A

    REM Get just the file name.
    SET NewName=%%~nxA
    REM Replace prefix.
    SET NewName=!NewName:MUZ-=muz!
    REM Replace suffix.
    SET NewName=!NewName:-KH=!

    ECHO Renaming to: !NewName!

    REM Rename the file. 
    RENAME "%%~fnxA" "!NewName!"

    ECHO.
)

ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the files follow the format:

```
prefix dash datawithnodash dash suffix . txt
```

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "prefix=MUZ"
    set "suffix=KH"
    set "extension=txt"

    pushd "c:\where\theFilesAre" && (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%a in ('
            dir /b /a-d /l "%prefix%-*-%suffix%.%extension%"
        ') do ren "%prefix%-%%b-%suffix%.%extension%" "%%a%%b.%extension%"
        popd
    )
```

This uses the dash as a delimiter to separate the elements of the filename, retrieving only the prefix and the valid data, discarding the rest. The list of files is retrieved with a `dir` command, requesting it in lower case to adapt the prefix case.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand regular expressions, then it quite simple using [JREN.BAT - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that renames files via regular expression search and replace.](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) JREN.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Regular expressions allow specification of very precise renaming rules.

The one liner below looks for:

- any set of characters except dash (the prefix)
- then a dash
- then any set of digits
- then a dash followed by any set of characters except dash (the suffix)
- ending with .txt (the extension, case insensitive)

It preserves the prefix and the numbers and the extension, making the entire thing lower case

```
jren "^([^-]+)-(\d+)-[^-]+(\.txt)$" "lc($1+$2+$3)" /i /j
```