# Replace filename in same directory according to project requirement

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have 4 types of graphics: figure, table, equation and inline equation.

There are above 500 such graphic in same directory. The problem is that I want to convert it into project requirement like this:

**MUZ-171669-KH_eq_01.gif** must convert to **muz123451669e001.gif**

**MUZ-171669-KH_eq_03a.gif** must convert to **muz123451669e03a.gif**

**MUZ-171669-KH_fig_10.gif** must convert to **muz1234516690010.gif**

**MUZ-171669-KH_fig_11a.gif** must convert to **muz123451669011a.gif**

**MUZ-171669-KH_ineq_01.gif** must convert to **muz123451669r001.gif**

**MUZ-171669-KH_ineq_04a.gif** must convert to **muz123451669r04a.gif**

**MUZ-171669-KH_t_01.gif** must convert to **muz123451669t001.gif**

**MUZ-171669-KH_t_02b.gif** must convert to **muz123451669t02b.gif**

That means:

Prefix **MUZ** must be converted to **muz12345**.

Project code number **171669**  must be converted to **1669**. This change according to graphics series like 1669, 1670, 1671 and so on, i.e. **171670**  must be converted to **1670**.

**171671** must be converted to **1671** and so on.

Now four types of SUFFIX graphics name:

They should be always convert to **4 digit** only like:

**eq_01** must be converted to **e001**.

**eq_03a** must be converted to **e03a**.

**fig_10** must be converted to **0010**.

**fig_11a** must be converted to **011a**.

**ineq_01** must be converted to **r001**.

**ineq_04a** must be converted to **r04a**.

**t_01** must be converted to **t001**.

**t_02b** must be converted to **t02b**.

Sometimes **eq_03a, fig_11a, ineq_04a, t_02b** suffix occur. In that case they should be converted like this **e03a, 011a, r04a, t02b** - FOUR DIGIT ONLY.

4 graphic have file number between **000** to **999**, i.e. **0001** to **0999**, **r001** to **r999**, **e001** to **e999**, **t001** to **t999**.

I have the code below. But that code is not working for figure and inline equation graphics.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "tokens=1-7delims=-_." %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "MUZ-*-*_*_*.gif" ') DO (
    IF "%%g"=="" (
        SET "num2=%%b"
        SET "fig=%%d"
        SET "num3=00%%e"
        REN "%%a-%%b-%%c_%%d_%%e.%%f" "muz12345!num2:~-4!!fig:~0,1!!num3:~-3!.%%f"
    )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a batch file with following code in the directory with the image files:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (MUZ-17????-KH_eq_??.*) do (
    set "OldFileName=%%~F"
    set "NewFileName=muz12345!OldFileName:~6,4!e0!OldFileName:~17,2!%%~xF"
    ren "!OldFileName!" "!NewFileName!"
)
for %%F in (MUZ-17????-KH_eq_???.*) do (
    set "OldFileName=%%~F"
    set "NewFileName=muz12345!OldFileName:~6,4!e!OldFileName:~17,3!%%~xF"
    ren "!OldFileName!" "!NewFileName!"
)
for %%F in (MUZ-17????-KH_fig_??.*) do (
    set "OldFileName=%%~F"
    set "NewFileName=muz12345!OldFileName:~6,4!00!OldFileName:~18,2!%%~xF"
    ren "!OldFileName!" "!NewFileName!"
)
for %%F in (MUZ-17????-KH_fig_???.*) do (
    set "OldFileName=%%~F"
    set "NewFileName=muz12345!OldFileName:~6,4!0!OldFileName:~18,3!%%~xF"
    ren "!OldFileName!" "!NewFileName!"
)
for %%F in (MUZ-17????-KH_ineq_??.*) do (
    set "OldFileName=%%~F"
    set "NewFileName=muz12345!OldFileName:~6,4!r0!OldFileName:~19,2!%%~xF"
    ren "!OldFileName!" "!NewFileName!"
)
for %%F in (MUZ-17????-KH_ineq_???.*) do (
    set "OldFileName=%%~F"
    set "NewFileName=muz12345!OldFileName:~6,4!r!OldFileName:~19,3!%%~xF"
    ren "!OldFileName!" "!NewFileName!"
)
for %%F in (MUZ-17????-KH_t_??.*) do (
    set "OldFileName=%%~F"
    set "NewFileName=muz12345!OldFileName:~6,4!t0!OldFileName:~16,2!%%~xF"
    ren "!OldFileName!" "!NewFileName!"
)
for %%F in (MUZ-17????-KH_t_???.*) do (
    set "OldFileName=%%~F"
    set "NewFileName=muz12345!OldFileName:~6,4!t!OldFileName:~16,3!%%~xF"
    ren "!OldFileName!" "!NewFileName!"
)
endlocal
```